# Sugarcrm: custom dependencies for conditional readonly fields

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I want to make all fields/the entire record readonly once the sales stage is "Closed Won" and the user is not an administrator.

```
<?php
global $current_user;
$dependencies['Opportunities']['lock_opportunity_dep'] = array(
    'hooks' => array("edit"),
    'trigger' => 'and(equal($sales_stage, "Closed Won"),equal($current_user->is_admin, true))',
    //'triggerFields' => array('sales_stage'),
    'onload' => true,
    'actions' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'ReadOnly',
            'params' => array(
                'target' => 'description',
                'value' => 'true',
            ),
        ),
        //.. all other fields here...
        array(
            'name' => 'ReadOnly',
            'params' => array(
                'target' => 'name',
                'value' => 'true',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

The above does not work; when I remove the admin check, the fields are locked correctly, so it appears $current_user cannot be used as part of the trigger because it is not a field in the Opportunity module.

1. How do I check whether the current user is an admin and use it as part of the trigger?
2. How can I loop through all fields in the module (in this case, Opportunities) instead of having to manually specify a ReadOnly array for each field?

Comment: which version of sugar you are using ?

Comment: SugarCRM Enterprise, Version 7.8.0.0 (Build 1700)

Comment: try to write your code in record.js

Comment: The problem with that approach is that it will only affect it in this specific view; these fields will still be editable in mobile view for example.
I'd prefer to apply the logic to only one spot instead of having to apply it to every js for each view (and any view that could be created in the future)

Comment: there is only two option either use java script  or calculated field.

Comment: @AmiteshKumar: How can we set field to Readonly using calculated field?

Comment: calculated field is always read only.